# Probability of independent events, quick question

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Quick question, if I have two independent events say $A$ and $B$ then I can write one event, such as $A$ as:

$A=A $\ $B$ , likewise $P(A) =P(A $\ $B$)

[image]

Correct?

Comment: Quick answer: yes

Comment: That is a very quick and very incorrect answer @GAVD.

Comment: First of all for the notation you should be writing a vertical bar $\mid$ for conditional probability but not the back slash $\backslash$. Back slash in set theory are used for the relative complementary set, or the difference. Secondly, the independence property is a property depends on the probability measure - for the same pair of set, they can be independent in one measure and dependent in other measure. So you cannot ignore the probability measure behind, and we cannot tell two sets are independent or not by solely looking at the set. Venn's diagram provide little help here.

Comment: By $\backslash $, do you mean complement, or conditional? There is a difference between $A | B$ and $A \setminus B$.

Comment: @ glockm15 Do not confuse the meanings of the terms "Independent" and "Mutually exclusive"!!!  When $A$ and $B$ are independent, $A\setminus B$ is not equal to $A$.  That happens to be true for mutually exclusive events, but not for independent events.

Comment: @BGM $A=A\mid B$ does not make any sense where $\mid$ is the conditional probability symbol, leading me to assume that the $\setminus$ was intentional and can only mean set difference.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes I never seen this abuse of notation before too and make no sense. Sometimes I am lazy which abuse the notation with $Y\mid X = x$ which use in the context to saying the distribution of $Y$ conditonal on the event $X = x$. But formally speaking the notation $\mid$ for independence should be used in indicating the conditional probability measure we are working with, so you will see them within the operators $\Pr \mathbb{P}$, expectation $\mathbb{E}$, variance, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*TLDR: No, not for independent events, but yes for mutually exclusive events*)

---

To reiterate what is said in comments:

We notate set difference with $\setminus$.  That is to say $A\setminus B = \{x~:~x\in A,x\notin B\}$.  We would have then $Pr(A\setminus B)$ is the probability that $A$ occurs and $B$ does not occur simultaneously.

We notate conditional probability with $\mid$.  That is to say $Pr(A\mid B)$ denotes the probability that $A$ has occurred given knowledge that $B$ has occurred.

Given two events $A$ and $B$ of a probability space, the following statements are equivalent:

- The two events $A$ and $B$ are said to be **mutually exclusive** (*to one another*).
- $A\cap B = \emptyset$
- $A\setminus B = A$
- $B\setminus A = B$

In layman's terms, if $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive that means that they cannot happen at the same time.  In particular, if it is known that $B$ occurred then it is impossible for $A$ to have also occurred simultaneously, i.e. $P(A\mid B)=0$.

---

Given two events $A$ and $B$ of a probability space, the following statements are equivalent:

- The two events $A$ and $B$ are said to be **independent** (*of one another*).
- $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$
- $Pr(A\mid B) = Pr(A)$
- $Pr(B\mid A) = Pr(B)$

In layman's terms, independent events have no influence over one another.  Even if we know that $B$ has occurred, this gives us no knowledge and does not influence our guess as to whether or not $A$ has occurred (*almost the exact opposite scenario as for mutually exclusive events*).

---

You asked in your question whether or not given that $A$ and $B$ are *independent* if $A=A\setminus B$ and $Pr(A)=Pr(A\setminus B)$.  No, at least not so long as $B$ occurs with probability greater than zero.  These would have been true for mutually exclusive events but not for independent events.  I cannot stress enough that mutual exclusivity and independence are totally different and should never be confused with one another.

Instead, $Pr(A\setminus B) = Pr(A\cap B^c) = Pr(A)\times (1-Pr(B))\neq Pr(A)$ so long as $Pr(B)\neq 0$

Answer (score 2):

No. For example, suppose that we flip a pair of coins, and $A$ is the event that the first  coin is heads, and $B$ is the event that the second coin is heads. Then $A$ and $B$ are independent and $A =\{HH,HT\}$, $B=\{HH,TH\}$, and $A\setminus B=\{HT\}$.